# Functional test for emails (subject and title)

Tags: emails, 9, testing

Question: How can a Drupal Functional Test (extenting BrowserTestBase) check for a certain Mail-Subject and Mail-Body defined in hook_mail in a custom module ?

Context:

I have a custom module which sends an email to certain people in case a new node of a certain bundle is created.

There is a Functional Test (BrowserTestbase) for this in the same way the User Module is doing it for Core:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21tests%21Drupal%21KernelTests%21Core%21Action%21EmailActionTest.php/function/EmailActionTest%3A%3AtestEmailAction/8.9.x

This test is green. Subject and Body are Checked after

```
$captured_emails = $this->drupalGetMails(); 

$this->assertEqual($captured_emails[0]['params']['subject'],"My desired Subject");

$this->assertEqual($captured_emails[0]["params"]["body"], "My desired Body");
```

BUT the actual Mails which are delivered do not have a subject AND do not have a body ! How is that possible ? I made a mistake in the custom module when I wanted to send the Email:

```
$mailManager->mail('my_custom', $key, $recipient, $langcode, $params, $from_email);
```

The first Parameter value was wrong. Like the module is named "my_awesome" but not "my_custom". In this case Drupal won't call the hook_mail Implementation in my_awesome_mail therefore the $message Object will not be filled with subject and body. There are no complains or exceptions. The Test is green the mail is empty.

Comment: The link in your post is a Kernel test, not a Functional test, and it tests the core EmailAction plugin. It does not test mail you send yourself via $mailManager->mail() with your own hook_mail(). We would have to see your hook_mail() and the full test function in order to help you figure out why your custom module doesn't include a body or subject. I suspect your hook_mail() is wrong - one of this mandatory things you must do in hook_mail() is to set the subject and body properly - it is not enough to pass the values to $mailManager->mail().

Comment: Yes as I wrote the module parameter in mailmanager->mail was wrong and hook_mail was not called. Thats why the test is green but the email that was send has no body and no subject. The question here is: how can I write a test that is red because subject and body are missing ? And even more complicated: how can i write this test independet from what kind auf mail plugin ( drupal default, smyfony-/swiftmail, sesmailer,…) is installed ?

Comment: No, the test is green because the test is testing EmailAction, and is not testing your code at all. Or at least that's what I gather from your post. You still haven't shown the test code you're using. If you want to use a Kernel test, copy something like core/modules/user/tests/src/Kernel/UserMailNotifyTest.php and modify it for your code. The basic outline of the test code is 1) setup your test environment, 2) call your function that sends mail, 3) use $this-getMails() to recover any sent mails from the buffer, then check the details of the message(s).

Comment: So how is it possible to test hook_mail in a cutom module meaningful ? It is also never tested in core isn‘t it ?